# Por que instanciar objetos usando a keyword new é hardcoded?

Tags: java, spring, instanciar-objeto, annotation, java-bean

Estou aprendendo Spring, e por diversas vezes, me deparei com instrutores resolvendo o "problema" da instanciação de objetos sendo feita pela palavra-chave `new`, como em:

`private SpeakerRepository repository = new HibernateSpeakerRepositoryImpl();`

Normalmente, para se resolver isto, usam a anotação Autowired(injeção de dependência), com a justificativa de que usar a instanciação por `new`, deixa o código hard coded.

Não consigo entender como a a palavra-chave `new` deixa o código hard-coded.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: A questão de poder ser considerado "Hard Coded" é que deve se dar preferência em usar o mecanismo de gestão de dependência do Spring.
Criar `@Bean` e injetar usando o `@Autowired`, é preferível utilizar um construtor para receber as dependências do que usar o `@Autowired` nas propriedades.

Answer (score 0):

Imagina agora que o seu SpeakerRepository é usado em 40 classes, e por algum motivo você precisa alterar a implementação em todas elas, isso iria te dar um puta trabalho, mas caso a implementação esteja no bean

Agora imagina isso

```
@ Bean
public SpeakerRepository speakerRepository(){
return new HibernateSpeakerRepositoryImpl()
}
```

Caso você precise alterar, apenas essa linha será alterada e o spring vai entender que mudou em todos os lugares.

Comment: Só isso não é vantagem. As classes que usam o repositório devem depender somente da interface, já a implementação pode ser passada tanto via injeção de dependência tradicional (_constructor injection_) como via framework de DI como o Spring. Fazendo certinho dá pra mudar uma vez só a implementação de qualquer  dos dois jeitos num ponto só. A vantagem que eu vejo é a escolha da implementação ser feita em tempo de execução e não de compilação, só não sei o benefício claro disso. Nem separar configuração de uso é vantagem exclusiva. A desvantagem: afasta a instanciação do lugar em que é usada.

Answer (score 0):

O problema de usar o `new` nesse caso é justamente essa maneira de injetar essa dependência em uma classe. O Spring fornece recursos para você fazer isso sem precisar instanciar os objetos dessa maneira. As maneiras mais comuns e utilizadas de injetar seriam com o **@Autowired** ou pelo próprio **construtor** da classe que injeta esse repository, essas são consideradas boas práticas em relação a injeção de dependências do Spring, pois garantem que toas as dependências necessárias serão injetadas. Além disso, pensando em um estrutura REST, o seu controller que injetaria o service, com a injeção pelo construtor ou @Autowired fica muito mais simples, pois não é necessário colocar todas as dependências do service no momento de injetar ele. Alguns outros casos como classes de Conversão de DTO ou Factory, que não possuem outras dependências sendo injetadas nelas, podem ser injetadas em uma classe com a keyword `new` sem problemas ao meu ver, como um qualquer outro objeto.

Uma maneira de fazer essa implementação do repository seria, você criar uma outra interface, chamada `SpeakerRepositoryCustom`, e nela colocar os métodos abstratos que você deseja sobrescrever em uma implementação, então fazer com que a sua interface `SpeakerRepository` estenda de sua interface Custom, assim possibilitando que você faça uma classe como a `HibernateSpeakerRepositoryImpl` sobrescrevendo as implementações dessa sua classe Custom, sem impactar na hierarquia do repo `SpeakerRepository` (caso ele estenda de outra interface como JpaRepository). Então injetar esse SpeakerRepository na sua classe de serviço com uma das opções que citei anteriormente.